# WARNING: At least one of your NS name does not seem a valid host name

Tags: domain-name-system, web-hosting, reverse-dns, dns-zone

So here is the issue I am having. When I run a DNS check on my TLD I am getting conflicting results. The domain name is newage.design and my NameServers are NS1.newage.design, NS2.newage.design, and NS3.newage.design

When I run the DNS check I get the following error:WARNING: At least one of your NS name does not seem a valid host name

I also noticed running a trace route of my domain name newage.design I am finding that it returns this as the final destination logix.aixair.org (162.246.57.163)

162.246.57.163 is my IP but I have no clue who or what logix.aixair.org is. Any idea whats causing this? All my sites are loading just fine and things seem great, so not sure what is happening here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most obvious problem is the PTR or reverse dns of the A records for two of your Name servers does not resolve to anything or is non existent.

Check here - [pingdom dnscheck](http://dnscheck.pingdom.com/?domain=newage.design)

Below, you can see ns1.newage.design and ns2.newage.design are the culprit -

```
$for x in $(dig +short newage.design. ns); do echo -n "$x: " ; y=$(host $(dig +short $x) | awk '{print $NF}'); echo -n " $y : " ; dig +short $y ; echo;done

ns3.newage.design.:  toadshop.com. : 192.184.87.18
ns2.newage.design.:  ns4.ktwebservers.net. : 
ns1.newage.design.:  logix.aixair.org. :
```

privatesystems.net seems to control the reverse dns zone, either directly or indirectly you might need to reach out to them to fix the issue -

```
$dig +trace 163.57.246.162.in-addr.arpa ptr

; > DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.23.rc1.el6_5.1 > +trace 163.57.246.162.in-addr.arpa ptr
;; global options: +cmd
.           3600000 IN  NS  H.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
.           3600000 IN  NS  D.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
.           3600000 IN  NS  B.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
.           3600000 IN  NS  M.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
.           3600000 IN  NS  K.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
.           3600000 IN  NS  J.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
.           3600000 IN  NS  F.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
.           3600000 IN  NS  E.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
.           3600000 IN  NS  I.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
.           3600000 IN  NS  G.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
.           3600000 IN  NS  L.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
.           3600000 IN  NS  C.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
.           3600000 IN  NS  A.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
;; Received 496 bytes from 192.168.10.109#53(192.168.10.109) in 4921 ms

in-addr.arpa.       172800  IN  NS  a.in-addr-servers.arpa.
in-addr.arpa.       172800  IN  NS  b.in-addr-servers.arpa.
in-addr.arpa.       172800  IN  NS  c.in-addr-servers.arpa.
in-addr.arpa.       172800  IN  NS  d.in-addr-servers.arpa.
in-addr.arpa.       172800  IN  NS  e.in-addr-servers.arpa.
in-addr.arpa.       172800  IN  NS  f.in-addr-servers.arpa.
;; Received 421 bytes from 193.0.14.129#53(193.0.14.129) in 96 ms

162.in-addr.arpa.   86400   IN  NS  v.arin.net.
162.in-addr.arpa.   86400   IN  NS  y.arin.net.
162.in-addr.arpa.   86400   IN  NS  z.arin.net.
162.in-addr.arpa.   86400   IN  NS  u.arin.net.
162.in-addr.arpa.   86400   IN  NS  r.arin.net.
162.in-addr.arpa.   86400   IN  NS  x.arin.net.
162.in-addr.arpa.   86400   IN  NS  w.arin.net.
;; Received 165 bytes from 203.119.86.101#53(203.119.86.101) in 234 ms

57.246.162.in-addr.arpa. 86400  IN  NS  ptr02.privatesystems.net.
57.246.162.in-addr.arpa. 86400  IN  NS  ptr01.privatesystems.net.
;; Received 103 bytes from 192.42.93.32#53(192.42.93.32) in 81 ms

163.57.246.162.in-addr.arpa. 86400 IN   PTR logix.aixair.org.
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I was able to get this resolved by contacting my provider and creating PTR records and rDNS records.

Answer (score 1):

What tool gave you that error? I can't find anything too serious, except for some reverse DNS issues.

I get `toadshop.com (162.246.57.20)` as your last hop. And via reverse DNS query.

```
$ host newage.design
newage.design has address 162.246.57.20
newage.design mail is handled by 0 newage.design.
$ host 162.246.57.20
20.57.246.162.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer toadshop.com.
```

That is the IP that all three of your DNS servers respond with as well

```
Using domain server:
Name: ns3.newage.design
Address: 162.246.57.20#53
Aliases: 

newage.design has address 162.246.57.20
newage.design mail is handled by 0 newage.design.
```

It just looks like your reverse DNS is not setup correctly. You will need ask your provider to do that for you. And from what you said about having a different IP, it makes me wonder if you are using dynamic IP addressing.  And perhaps that explains why your reverse DNS changed from logix.aixair.org to toadshop.com.

And Daniel t. is correct, your name servers also have similar reverse DNS issues.